# how to choose the right library version

Tags: android, maven, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

maybe it is because I don't understand it but choosing the right version of dependency libraries to specify in the build.gradle file is a big mess.

How do we know which versions to choose and which versions are compatible with other versions?

Now that I have discovered maven.google.com I think I can see all the versions available to me.

Most recently I am dealing with Firebase libraries.  I need both messaging and core. At this writing messaging is at 17.3.4 and core is at 16.0.4.  But if I build with those versions I get an error that says cannot access zzbfm - what ever that is.

I finally got a clean compile with the following but this combination was achieved by trial and error taking an hour or so...

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1' 
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
> ```

It would be nice if the answer were "always use the latest version" but that certainly isn't the answer.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are not really missing anything. Version compatibility is mainly a thing of trial and error. What you can do:

- Only add the artifacts you really use in your code. Don't add transitive dependencies.
- Look at potential conflicts in the transitive dependencies and make trials, starting with the newer version.

Generally: Try to use as few dependencies as possible, this reduces the hassle.